# iTextSharp jbig2 encoder

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, itext

```
string imgfile = @"C:\users\me\desktop\test.jpg";

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imgfile);
Bitmap bw = ConvertTo1Bpp(bmp); //make b+w

Document doc = 
    new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, 
    new System.IO.FileStream(
        @"C:\users\me\desktop\test.pdf", 
        System.IO.FileMode.Create, 
        System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite));

iTextSharp.text.ImgJBIG2 i = 
    ((iTextSharp.text.ImgJBIG2)iTextSharp.text.ImgJBIG2.GetInstance(
        bmp, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp));

doc.Open();
doc.Add(i);
doc.Close();
```

I cant find any good documentation for this with iTextSharp. What I am trying to do is take a Jpeg file and convert it into a pdf embedded as a black and white JBig2 image. The error I get is an InvalidCastException between "iTextSharp.text.ImageRaw" and "iTextSharp.text.ImageJBig2"... is there an alternative to what I have above?

**EDIT**
ImgJBig2 just represents an image already encoded in JBig2 I believe now. What I am looking for is something that will take a Bitmap and encode it into a BW JBig2 Bitmap that I can put into a Pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell there's not a lot of options for encoding JBig2 and no native free ones.

- [Windows Imaging SDK ($2500+)](http://www.snowbound.com/rastermaster_windows/windows_overview.html)
- [JBIG2 Compression Codec SDK for .NET ($1,800)](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/jbig2)
- [jbig2enc (free but c code only)](https://github.com/agl/jbig2enc)

The last creates a CLI program that you might be able to P/Invoke into or at worst script against so I think that's your best option if you don't want to pay. Does JBIG2 offer such greater compression over other formats?

Comment: yes, it does for B+W images. I am using jbig2enc in my toolkit now but I haven't taken the time to test it out on 64 bit. Unfortunately that is all our servers will run anymore. I will have to work it out though. thanks!

Comment: @Tom Fobear, are you P/Invoking it or scripting over the command line? I'm just curious in case this ever comes up again.